# Registration form - upload image

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, registration

I'm working on a registration form for a website, I'm trying to upload a photo to the server and pass the file path on to the database.

This is probably just a simple issue, as i'm quite the beginner to php and mysql.

Here's my standard form, which we'll call **register.php**. I cut out all other input than the image.

```
<form name="reg" action="code_exec.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
    <input type="file" id="inputImage" Name="photo">
    <button class="btn btn-large btn-success" type="submit">Register</button>
</form>
```

This is the execution file, which we'll call **code_exec.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
include('connection.php');

$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$mname = $_POST['mname'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$contact = $_POST['contact'];
$pic = $_POST['pic'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$skype = $_POST['skype'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

//This is the directory where images will be saved 
$target = "upload/"; 
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']); 

//This gets all the other information from the form 
$pic = ($_FILES['photo']['name']); 

//Writes the photo to the server 
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target)) { 
    //Tells you if its all ok 
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory"; 
} else { 
    //Gives an error if its not 
    echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
} 

mysql_query("INSERT INTO member(fname, lname, gender, address, contact, picture, username, password, skype, email, photo)VALUES('$fname', '$lname', '$mname', '$address', '$contact', '$pic', '$username', '$password', '$skype', '$email', '$pic')");

header("location: index.php?remarks=success");
mysql_close($con);

?>
```

How do I find the path of the image file?

Comment: Don't insert `$_POST` data directly! It's a major security issue http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection. See : http://xkcd.com/327/ and 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained, are [officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp) and can be [dangerous in live code](http://bit.ly/4zUdtT). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: [Please, indent code correctly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style). Without indentation, the code is harder to understand.

Answer (score 1):

In code

> Before

```
<form name="reg" action="code_exec.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
    <input type="file" id="inputImage" Name="photo">
    <button class="btn btn-large btn-success" type="submit">Register</button>
</form>
```

> After changes

```
<form name="reg" action="code_exec.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="inputImage" Name="photo">
    <button class="btn btn-large btn-success" type="submit">Register</button>
</form>
```

You just add 
**`enctype="multipart/form-data"`** in your html form tag

> Description

1.When you upload any types of files from form you must write **enctype** attribute in form element.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's easy, just add `$target` to your SQL query.

```
// Escape the string, so you wouldn't be affected by SQL injection.
// Move to MySQLi or PDO, and follow guide http://bobby-tables.com/php.html
// to have your queries automatically escaped, as it's easy to forget about
// using mysql_real_escape_string() (also, it's annoying to type it).
$target = mysql_real_escape_string($target);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO member(..., target) VALUES (..., '$target')");
```

Answer (score 0):

just use the layout i have provided:

for html use this keep in mind you can always improve it:

```
<form action="nameofthepage.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                    <table align="center" width="750">

                        <tr align="center">
                            <td colspan="6"><h2>Create an Account</h2></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td align="right">Customer Name:</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="c_name" required/></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td align="right">Customer Email:</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="c_email" required/></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td align="right">Customer Password:</td>
                            <td><input type="password" name="c_pass" required/></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td align="right">Customer Image:</td>
                            <td><input type="file" name="c_image" required/></td>
                        </tr>



                        <tr>
                            <td align="right">Customer Country:</td>
                            <td>
                            <select name="c_country">
                                <option>Select a Country</option>
                                <option>Afghanistan</option>
                                <option>India</option>
                                <option>Japan</option>
                                <option>Pakistan</option>
                                <option>Israel</option>
                                <option>Nepal</option>
                                <option>United Arab Emirates</option>
                                <option>United States</option>
                                <option>United Kingdom</option>
                            </select>

                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td align="right">Customer City:</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="c_city" required/></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td align="right">Customer Contact:</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="c_contact" required/></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td align="right">Customer Address</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="c_address" required/></td>
                        </tr>


                    <tr align="center">
                        <td colspan="6"><input type="submit" name="register" value="Create Account" /></td>
                    </tr>



                    </table>

                </form>
```

and for the php use:

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['register'])){


        $ip = getIp();

        $c_name = $_POST['c_name'];
        $c_email = $_POST['c_email'];
        $c_pass = $_POST['c_pass'];
        $c_image = $_FILES['c_image']['name'];
        $c_image_tmp = $_FILES['c_image']['tmp_name'];
        $c_country = $_POST['c_country'];
        $c_city = $_POST['c_city'];
        $c_contact = $_POST['c_contact'];
        $c_address = $_POST['c_address'];


        move_uploaded_file($c_image_tmp,"customer/customer_images/$c_image");

         $insert_c = "insert into customers (customer_ip,customer_name,customer_email,customer_pass,customer_country,customer_city,customer_contact,customer_address,customer_image) values ('$ip','$c_name','$c_email','$c_pass','$c_country','$c_city','$c_contact','$c_address','$c_image')";

        $run_c = mysqli_query($con, $insert_c); 

        $sel_cart = "select * from cart where ip_add='$ip'";

        $run_cart = mysqli_query($con, $sel_cart); 

        $check_cart = mysqli_num_rows($run_cart); 

        if($check_cart==0){

        $_SESSION['customer_email']=$c_email; 

        echo "<script>alert('Account has been created successfully, Thanks!')</script>";
        echo "<script>window.open('customer/my_account.php','_self')</script>";

        }
        else {

        $_SESSION['customer_email']=$c_email; 

        echo "<script>alert('Account has been created successfully, Thanks!')</script>";

        echo "<script>window.open('checkout.php','_self')</script>";


        }
    }





?>
```

BUT DON'T FORGET CHANGING THE NAMES OF THE TABLES AND VALUES
HOPE IT HEPLED!

Answer (score 0):

When you used `move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target)`, the image moved to your `$target` path. So the path for image is the `$target`. Now just use `$target` instead of `$pic` on the query function  you used. Like-

```
$target = mysql_real_escape_string($target);  //escape string for sql injection 
mysql_query("INSERT INTO member(fname, lname, gender, address, contact, picture, username, password, skype, email, photo)VALUES('$fname', '$lname', '$mname', '$address', '$contact', '$target', '$username', '$password', '$skype', '$email', '$pic')");
```

Answer (score 0):

When to upload photo/media from form, you need to add `<form method="" action="" enctype = "multipart/form-data">` attribute to the form. Without that uploading of media will not work.

Also make sure to use `post` method only for media uploading